# New to C++: Creating a 2D array and having a correct assignment operator: Segmentation Error

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, assignment-operator

I am new to c++ and I have to create a 2D array using pointers. I have completed the creation of the array but I cannot run anything after the initial creation of the matrix due to a "Segmentation fault". I believe this is from my assignment operator, but I'm not sure. This could be from the copy constructor, but because we have to use pointers I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef My_Matrix_H
#define My_matrix_H
#include "My_matrix.h"
#include <stdexcept>

My_matrix::My_matrix() //contructor
{
n = 0;
m = 0;
ptr = NULL;
}

My_matrix::My_matrix(int n1, int m1) //creation of the matrix
{

ptr = new int*[n1];
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = new int[m1];
    for (int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
    {
        ptr[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

}

My_matrix::My_matrix(const My_matrix& mat) //copy constructor
{

    n = mat.n;
    m = mat.m;
    ptr = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j] = mat.ptr[i][j];
        }
    }

}

My_matrix::~My_matrix() //destructor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[] ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] ptr;
}

My_matrix& My_matrix::operator=(const My_matrix& mat) //assignmemt operator
{

    n = mat.n;
    m = mat.m;
    ptr = new int*[n];
    cout << "1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "2" << endl;
        ptr[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "3" << endl;
            ptr[i][j] = mat.ptr[i][j];
        }
    }

}

void My_matrix::elemset(int i, int j, int num) //puts stuff into matrix
{
ptr[i][j] = num;
}
}#endif
```

Comment: why do you allocate memory in `operator=`? You already did that in the constructor and just need to copy the values

Comment: @tobi303 It seems to be accounting for assignment between matrices with different sizes.

Comment: Note that you are not releasing your previously allocated arrays whenever you assign, which is allocating new arrays.

Comment: Have you checked which line is causing the segfault with a debugger?

Comment: I find it suspicious that you are using an include guard in the implementation file, and that it's name matches what you would expect for the header you include.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux now i get it. when i see too many news my brain sometimes stops working ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux would I insert a delete[] in the copy constuctor somewhere? This is a project and pointers are something I am fuzzy on

Comment: @Alowishious -- Please use copy / swap: `My_matrix& My_matrix::operator=(const My_matrix& mat) { My_matrix temp(mat); std::swap(n,temp.n);std::swap(m, temp.m);std::swap(ptr, temp.ptr); return *this;}`.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) -- there is no need to write assignment operators, basically duplicating the copy constructor.

Comment: Use a std::vector of size row*col instead of new[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer. A copy/swap was most effective, as given by @PaulMcKenzie.

```
My_matrix& My_matrix::operator=(const My_matrix& mat) 

{ 

 My_matrix temp(mat); 
 std::swap(n,temp.n);
 std::swap(m, temp.m);
 std::swap(ptr, temp.ptr); 
 return *this;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[1] In `My_matrix(int,int)` members `n` and `m` are not set (this is cause of all troubles, if you call any of these members (copy constructor, assignment operator or destructor) after creating object by `My_matrix(int,int)` without setting `n,m`, your application must crash).

[2] `My_matrix::operator=` should return `*this`.

[3] In `My_matrix::operator=` you should delete previous allocated data.